# Angular Feature, Shared and Core modules dependencies

Tags: angular

I've a doubt how to organize Angular modules.

Angular suggests that Feature module should import Shared module (with reusable components) but not Core module (with reusable services). Conceptually, for my point of view, Shared and Core modules provide reusable entities for Future modules and it's strange that they should be treated differently. It makes harder to understand Future module dependencies since all of them spread across Future module services and components. As result refactoring might be difficult because there is no one place with a high level deps overview.

Maybe I miss something and there is other way how to organize modules? Have you faced the same problem or it's not a problem at all from your perspective?

Answer (score 1):

based on Angular [Guideline](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#core-feature-module)

CoreModule will be imported in AppModule, and it will be available for shared and all featureModules, this is why they said **Avoid** importing in feature module

Also if you see the [example](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#overall-structural-guidelines) of folder structure there are some services in SharedModule, it means services are not limited to CoreModule. But single-use classes and singleton services will be in CoreModule

> **Consider** collecting numerous, auxiliary, single-use classes inside a core module to simplify the apparent structure of a feature module.
>
> **Consider** calling the application-wide core module, CoreModule. Importing CoreModule into the root AppModule reduces its complexity and emphasizes its role as orchestrator of the application as a whole.
>
> **Do** create a feature module named CoreModule in a core folder (e.g. app/core/core.module.ts defines CoreModule).
>
> **Do** put a singleton service whose instance will be shared throughout the application in the CoreModule (e.g. ExceptionService and LoggerService).
>
> **Do** import all modules required by the assets in the CoreModule (e.g. CommonModule and FormsModule).
>
> **Avoid** importing the CoreModule anywhere except in the AppModule.

Comment: Maybe to add.   The importance of correctly seperating and importing modules/services becomes aparent when you start lazy-loading :)

Comment: Yeah I understand how Core module import works. It eventuallly provides services for all feature modules.
I don't like the idea that Feature module uses Core services 
but does not define Core module as a dependency. It's a hidden dependecy which is not obvious from the first glance. Core module might have dozens services and it's not clear which are used in a Feature.

Comment: @VitaliiMishchenko just note only application-wide services will be defined in core, others will be provided in their own modules